# ember-changeset-validations not working as expected with a boolean

Tags: validation, ember.js

I have an Ember object that has as attribute a boolean field that I want to validate with ember-changeset-validations.

It is the typical "Agree to terms" checkbox.

Here is the hbs code:

```
{{one-way-checkbox changeset.agree_terms 
class="form-control" 
update=(action (mut changeset.agree_terms))}}

{{#each changeset.error.agree_terms.validation as |error|}}
    <span class="text-danger help-block m-l-3">{{t (concat 'bookings.error.' error)}}</span>
{{/each}}
```

I have a validations file, where the particular validation for this member of changeset is:

```
agree_terms: validateFormat({
regex: /^(true)$/,
message: 'You need to agree on Terms!'
})
```

Thing is, for some reason this never validates to TRUE correctly, I always get the error message...any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky; but I figured that out. [ember-change-set-validations](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-changeset-validations) do make use of [ember-validators](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-validators) underneath. Since; you are using `validateFormat`;  the following [code](https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-validators/blob/master/addon/format.js#L64) is being run at the end. If you look at the link I have provided; there is a check `!canInvoke(value, 'match')` causes you the problem. Since the checked value of a checkbox is a boolean and you cannot invoke `match` on booleans you always end up having an invalid validation.

What can you do? Well; I am not an expert at `ember-change-set-validations` and `ember-validators` but it is pretty easy to write a custom validator. This is what I did in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/09bfa9316e9a4dd4841dad4f2cfd9bea?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). It seems to be working pretty fine.

What I understood is; it is not a good idea to use boolean values with `format` type validator (it clearly does not work); I only wished it was documented. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a bunch for the detailed answer, I might post this in ember-changeset-validations Github, so they can document it :)

Comment: That is a great idea; it might help others as well. Thanks.